Is there some known official rationalization of why Task.IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously always returns false
The most recent documentation forTask's explicit interface member implementation of IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously states the following:

true if the operation completed synchronously; otherwise, false.

According to this 2015 blogpost by Stephen Cleary and this stackoverflow answer from 2016, the property always returns false.
This is still the case in 2024 if we look at the source code which doesn't provide any further clarification as to why:
/// <summary>
/// Gets an indication of whether the asynchronous operation completed synchronously.
/// </summary>
/// <value>true if the asynchronous operation completed synchronously; otherwise, false.</value>
bool IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously => false;

The Task API infrastructure allows for a synchronous execution for example via:

Task.RunSynchronously
TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously

It is true that for all of this the TaskScheduler is involved, but for the synchronous execution I could find in the code it is almost exclusively done through calls to
protected abstract bool TryExecuteTaskInline (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued);

which returns according to the documentation
A Boolean value indicating whether the task was executed inline.

The documentation suggests that custom TaskScheduler implementers call the base TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTask which has access to the internal bool Task.ExecuteEntry()
Now at this point, we can't really pass the information to the task object that the task scheduler decided that it can run it synchronously instead of scheduling it.
But Microsoft could have introduced overloads to both base TaskScheduler.TryExecuteTask and internal Task.ExecuteEntry() accepting a bool runsInline which could be used to set internal flags upon successful completion that IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously could make use of. Or better yet they could have made those the only options from the beginning so to prevent custom task schedulers implementations from messing up by calling the wrong overload.
So, I am left to wonder:

Was it a non-priority/oversight at the time which locked the API in such a manner that it couldn't really be reliably introduced later on via the overloads
Was it a well-thought out design decision that a certain Task object won't be able to always determine reliably if completed synchronously or not. If so is there a link to (semi-)official rationalization of this because the official documentation is still silent/misleading about it.

If you know why it won't be feasible and provide some clear examples demonstrating it I will accept the answer in the event that no official link/position surfaces in another answer.

Note: TaskScheduler is not the only way of working with tasks, and quite likely now represents the minority of Task use-cases

This is pure speculation, but if I had to guess: because it doesn't know, and it is less harmful to give incorrect False than incorrect True. Tracking this would require an additional flag and the logic to set that flag correctly. Setting it during FromResult etc is probably fine, but giving the correct answer in all cases (TaskCompletionSource<T> etc) gets difficult - even tracking the thread-id at creation and signal doesn't really give the full story, as you could end up on the same thread-id after going truly async. So if you can't give a reliable correct value, giving a consistent value is probably safer than sometimes working (and sometimes: not).

Well sometimes, it can know. If we marked all TaskCompletionSource PromiseTask as false (although I think even this is theoretically possible), we can return true for the TaskScheduler's style task.

"sometimes" is not a good outcome

we could deem all TaskCompletionSource tasks as asynchronous by default, and the TaskScheduler task as synchronous/asynchronous and also provided a property IsPromise/TaskCompletionTask. Couldn't that have worked?

@IvanPetrov ok, but: to what end? what does it matter? to be worth all the effort of tracking this accurately, there should exists a good reason?

maybe there existed a good reason for having this initially on IAsyncResult like preventing stack dives from callbacks.  I am just looking for a text describing how and why all cases where IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously  was useful are solved by the rest of the Task API or just made irrelevant when using tasks compared to other IAsyncResult derived classes. Maybe by having ContinueWith invoking continuations asyncronously by default etc.

"but giving the correct answer in all cases (TaskCompletionSource<T> etc) gets difficult." -- I would use the word impossible, not difficult. Not even God himself could implement this property in a way that gives a 100% reliable answer in all cases.

@TheodorZoulias Sure you could.  If the result/exception is set before the TaskCompletionSource.Task property getter is ever called, the task is synchronous, if it's not, then it isn't, as there's a task that is observable before it is completed.  It's both simple (ish) to implement and 100% accurate.

@Servy i don't think it is correct to reason in terms of timing of access to Task property. TaskCompletionSource is a combinator, we might implement logic via Task.Run internally, and that would be async execution. I would agree, regardless of initial design reason of IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously consumers of Task should not care about how it was executed. Other story is writing our own async code, where we have hints mentioned.

@Servy here is a DoAsync method that returns synchronously a completed task: Task DoAsync() { TaskCompletionSource tcs = new(); Task task = tcs.Task; tcs.SetResult(); return task; } According to your logic the resulting Task would erroneously report that it completed asynchronously. The SetResult is called after reading the TaskCompletionSource.Task property.

@TheodorZoulias The task is always completed with respect to the caller of DoAsync, and yet the task was not always completed for the entire existence of that Task.  DoAsync, internally, had access to that task when it was uncompleted, thus from the perspective of that task, it was not completed synchronously.  It could have been accessed before it was completed.  It just happened to not be.

@Servy so you think that there is asynchrony hidden inside the DoAsync, although all work is done on the current thread, no work is done on any other thread, no work is done on any hardware device external to the CPU, and there is no thread-switch from the moment the DoAsync is invoked to the moment that the Task was been awaited? You would need an extremely twisted definition of asynchrony to justify this claim. You could test how much the community approves such a definition, by posting an answer and counting the votes.

@TheodorZoulias nothing prevented to design an API of TaskCompletionSource that allowed for setting how the task was completed, i.e. SetResult(bool completedSynchronously)

also this implementation somehow doesn't disavow IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously

@TheodorZoulias Considering such an answer isn't even attempting to answer the question asked, and would merit deletion, I'm not going to post it as an answer.  The question is not how to implement that interface in one's own asynchronous objects.  But I stated why my assumed definition of CompletedSynchronous was, namely that the task has a result upon construction, rather than relying on any definition over how it happens to be observed or implemented.  It's certainly not the only possible definition, but as others are, as you say, impossible to implement, they seem not useful.

@IvanPetrov you assume that the user of a TaskCompletionSource has in all cases 100% reliable knowledge about the correct value of the completedSynchronously parameter. That's a bold assumption to make, since it can be refuted by a single counterexample. Have you considered all possible scenarios where a TaskCompletionSource can be used, and concluded that the completedSynchronously is always known in all these diverse situations? Or you are just gambling?

@TheodorZoulias assuming that TaskScheduler tasks had this property set, can you come up with a single example of TaskCompletionSource not being able to decide if it did complete synchronously or not?

@Servy most C# developers would agree that there is absolutely nothing asynchronous in the DoAsync method. A property named CompletedSynchronously should use a definition of asynchrony that is consistent with other .NET APIs that use the same word, like the TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously or the TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously or the ChannelOptions.AllowSynchronousContinuations. You can't just come out of the blue and redefine this concept in a way that is unrecognizable, and defies most peoples' expectations.

@IvanPetrov yes. You can find an example in this answer, where I use a TaskCompletionSource and I have no idea if the antecedent task (t) completed synchronously or asynchronously. So I would be in trouble if I had to provide a value to a mandatory completedSynchronously parameter.

@TheodorZoulias that's kind of circular argumentation - you don't have idea because Task doesn't provide for IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously. But what if it did? The only argument against it so far is that TaskCompletionSource somehow won't work. I am looking for such an example.

@IvanPetrov sure, if all existing asynchronous APIs in all standard and 3rd party .NET libraries provided the CompletedSynchronous information, we could propagate this information during async/await composition etc. But the propagated information would be as reliable as the source information. We would have to deal with scenarios where the CompletedSynchronous is true, after having observed earlier that the IsCompleted was false. If the success of your business was dependent on the reliability of the CompletedSynchronous information, you'd be in trouble.

@TheodorZoulias not if bugs are reported/fixed as with all software. and btw IAsyncResult is an interface which everybody could have implemented in the wrong way. I am sure 3rd party implementation existed that worked for people in the APM days. See this question that we both answered and especially the part in the blog post again - eliminating stack dives was an issue that was resolved by CompletedSynchronously property.

@IvanPetrov so I guess what you ask me to do is to come up with an example of a primitive asynchronous operation, not composed, where the CompletedSynchronously cannot be determined reliably. Something related to networking, or the file system, or database drivers etc. I am not experienced with authoring primitive asynchronous APIs, so I can't tell if there are any challenges into providing the CompletedSynchronous information. Hopefully someone else can.

@TheodorZoulias yeah, above my paygrade as well. That's why I asked the question. A bit disappointed in stackoverflow lately when it comes to asking questions I want answered...

@TheodorZoulias re your edit: the [<T>] was correct; TCS exists without the generic type: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource

Marc yeah, I am aware that a non-generic version exists, but the [<T>] looks more like a syntactically erroneous <T[]> or like a hyperlink that went wrong. It didn't occurred to me that the brackets was a notation for "optional". I haven't seen this notation before.
